# Subscribe others to PowerBI report - Send automated mail with access to all pages

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

I have my powerbi report with multiple pages. I want to send weekly mails with the report to a group of people (i have scheduled data refresh for it, so its up to date).

In the subscribe pane, I can select a page of the report, I want to send out the whole report but dont want to create new subscription for each page

1. If I check the boxes for "Access to this report", "link of this report in powerbi" will they be able to access all the pages?
2. And what if I want to share only first x pages, and dont want to give access for the other pages

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, If you check the boxes for "Access to this report", "link of this report in powerbi" they will be able to access all the pages from the report.
2. Not particularly giving access to specific report pages but you can select and send specific pages from the report in the email.

You can send an automated email at set intervals, with an attached .pdf report.
In this report, you can indicate specific pages to export in the Pages `pageName -1` field.

The `pageName` parameter is different from the display page name. You can find the page name by navigating to the page in the Power BI service, and copying the last portion of the URL, as shown in the example below.

Example: `https://app.powerbi.com/groups/workspaceGuid/reports/reportGuid/xxxxxxxxxx`

**References:**
https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-automate-power-bi-report-export#create-a-flow-from-scratch